# How does a button click event know that an event handler returns a promise or not in Angular 14?

Tags: angular, typescript, events, async-await, promise

I'm playing around with Promises in Angular 14. While I do understand the basics of Promises, I couldn't understand how the button click event know when to await an async event handler that returns a Promise versus just executing an event handler that simply returns void.

I expect to see something like this `<button (async click)="await runAsync()">Run async</button>` on the component HTML template, but obviously that's not going to work. So how does it work?

Sample code below for comparison:

```
<button (click)="runSync()">Run sync</button>
<p>Count: {{ count }}</p>
<hr />
<p>How this button know that the event handler it is calling is async?</p>
<button (click)="runAsync()" [disabled]="disabled">Run async</button>
<p>Value: {{ value }}</p>
<p>Error: {{ error }}</p>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  count: number;
  value!: number;
  error!: number;
  disabled: boolean;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.count = 0;
    this.disabled = false;
  }

  runSync(): void {
    this.count++;
  }

  async runAsync(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      this.disabled = true;
      this.value = await this.getRandomValue(2000);
    } catch (e) {
      this.error = <number>e;
    } finally {
      this.disabled = false;
    }
  }

  private getRandomValue(delay: number): Promise<number> {
    return new Promise<number>((resolve, reject) => {
      const value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
      console.log(value);

      if (value < 6) setTimeout(() => resolve(value), delay);
      else reject(value);
    });
  }
}
```

Link to code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-85kph9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Thanks in advance!

Comment: (click) is an event firered by the dom and it executes the callback function that you link to it like runAsync(). The (click) event does not expect answer. So when you click on the button, runAsync will be excuted, and your value will be updated.

Comment: What is the purpose of two runSync methods?

Comment: @user1075296, does that mean `runAsync()` is executed synchronously?

Comment: @Jai, it is just an example to show that one method is sync and the other one is async

Comment: @ponki.d.monkey Isn't specific method for each button would be better?

Comment: @Jai, there are 2 methods in my example - `runSync()` and `runAsync()`

Comment: When runAsync() is run , that will trigger the promise, then that will wait the promise to be resolve. So, the (this.value) inside the method will be updated asynchronoulsy. In the end, the (click) event only trigger the method but does not expect a return. It looks a bit confusing due to type template limitation.